# An example of a UISplitViewController working with a multi level UINavigationController on an iPad

Tags: ipad, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have just spent a full day trying to get an iPad Split View Controller to work with a multi level (2 levels) Navigation Controller.  I can each one to work individually, but cannot get them to work together.  My application is quite simple: I want a two level navigation controller and when the user makes a selection at the second level, table information about the selection is displayed in the detail view.  For example: the first level of the navigation controller might be a list of states, the second level would be a list of cities within that state.  When a city is selected, a list (UITableView) of restaurants would be displayed for that city.  Can anyone point me to an example for an iPad that implements this functionality (or something close).  Thanks!!